# Confusion around the SKLearn GridSearchCV scoring parameter and using train test split

Tags: python, scikit-learn, rdkit

I'm a little bit confused about how GridSearchCV works with Train Test Split. 
As far as I know, when creating models for the dataset I'm using, a paper used roc-auc. 
I'm trying to replicate what this paper did, at least as well as I can. From reading a few other posts here, I've gathered that running GridSearchCV on the entire dataset is prone to overfitting, so we should split the data into a training partition and a testing partition. Then, we should run the training partition with GridSearchCV with whatever model and parameters, and then fit it, and then get a score using the test part of the dataset we set aside.

Now where I'm confused is with GridSearchCV, as far as I understand, it gives us scores for each of the folds that the data is split into when doing the search for parameters and using best_score_ we can pull the best of these scores. I don't understand what the scores represent and why you can pass in a scoring parameter to begin with, since the job of GridSearchCV is to always find the best possible parameters anyways? (Perhaps I'm making a poor assumption here but I'm assuming that there is an objective best set of parameters, regardless of scoring method). What I figured was that I would find the best parameters with GridSearchCV and then use the said parameters to create fit a model, and finally use that model and the partition I saved for testing and test it using the roc-auc scoring method.

So in the end, does it matter (if at all) what scoring methods I'm passing into GridSearchCV, as it will always look to give the best set of parameters anyways, which I will use to compute my final score with the testing partition?

Answer (score 1):

[This document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) may help.

- Here you see that the `scoring` parameter allows you to have various metrics, such as `roc_auc`. See here [all Scikit's metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter).
- Optimizing over different metrics result in different optimal parameters. Just think about optimizing precision versus recall. Optimizing precision leads to less false positives while optimizing recall leads to less false negatives.
- Also, in `GridSearchCV`, the `CV` stands for cross validated. Train/test splitting happens inside this function, it's taken care of. You only have to provide the splitter as an argument to `GridSearchCV`, for example `cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your swift reply. I have a few clarifying questions that I hope you wouldn't mind answering. From what I've read, GridSearchCV takes care of training and splitting, so I really don't need to split it manually myself. However, after reading this post (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436894/should-a-training-set-be-used-for-grid-search-with-cross-validation), the answer's (on that post) second bullet point mentions that they recommend to split it first, then train off of the train set. I could be misunderstanding, but it sounds like it conflicts your point.

Comment: Also, if I was to go without splitting the data as you said, which score would I want to record as the roc-auc (or whatever scoring method) that I found for the task / dataset? Would I pull the best prediction from the splits with best_prediction_ and call it a day? Thank you very much!!

Comment: So as the other post says, there is two options. One where you do train/validation/test split before the optimization, optimize on train, pick parameters on validation, validate parameters on test. 
As the other post mentions, the second approach is more robust. You do cross-validation inside the hyperparameter optimization. For every hyperparameter iteration, you cross-validate your metrics, making a more robust approach. This second approach is in line with my comment.

Comment: `GridSearchCV` returns a mean and standard deviation on the test score. You can chose what you want to do with that. Personally I always take the best (mean - 1std). The best score provided by Scikit is the best mean score, which can have a large variance over your splits. What you consider best is fully dependent on your conservatism.

Comment: Thank you once again, just to clarify, as I'm deathly afraid that I'm misreading everything, the second approach, where you do CV within the hyperparameter tuning, is taken care of as long as I call GridSearchCV, correct? I won't need to split my X and y data into train/test splits as GS will do that.

Comment: So right now, the idea I have is that with my data, I am going to run a GridSearchCV with the parameters I want to tune from (and use my desired scoring method, roc_auc as the scoring parameter). This should return as many scores as folds that I have. With these scores, it is up to me to decide how conservative I want to be with the "best score" and use the value I decide on to represent the accuracy of the model. Is there anything with this plan than sounds off to you?

Comment: Exactly. You only have to feed the argument 'cv' to your gridsearchcv. 
When it comes to selecting the best score, consider that best mean is optimal, the best mean penalized with one or more standard deviations is more robust.